# Display AJAX loading image for at least 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've being trying to solve this and none of the posts i've read seem to answer it for me.

I'm making .load calls and targetting the DB response into a div with class of "content"

My loading gif appears when I use the following:

```
$('#loading-image').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

However, my server responds with the succesfful ajax call really quickly and the .load displays the content in milliseconds.  I'd like it to pause for 2 seconds, display the loading dig and then show the content.

How can this be achieived?

Comment: Why do you want to make a fast ajax call appear to be slower?

Comment: I don't but my client likes the effect

Comment: If you want to delay loading content to the div I suggest firing a custom event on your success of the ajax call with a setTimeout

Comment: Then use your expertise and convince them otherwise. This will inevitably cause more errors than gains.

Comment: Agree with @limelights , doesn't make a lot of sense to delay a function only because the client likes looking at the loading gif. Save that for slow functions, if this is a millisecond ajax call, don't bother with the loading.

Comment: false delays are useful for user experience. It depends on your use case. I've found that conversion rates were higher on a sales funnel because I increased a progress wait time from milliseconds to 90 seconds.

Comment: Completely off topic, but 'client likes the effect' made me laugh. Talk about a 'worse is better' design pattern! You could probably get him to change his mind by suggesting that implementing it might force content 'below the fold'.

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. Experiment with the delay() function - which delays the execution and not the process/result.

   ```
   $( "#container" ).load( "content.txt").delay(2000);
   ```
2. Hide the contents and use setTimeout to display them. Something along these lines:

   ```
   $( "#container" ).hide();

   $( "#container" ).load( "content.txt", function( response, status, xhr ) {
      if ( status == "success" ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $( "#container" ).show('slow');
        }, 3000);
      }
   });
   ```

I would use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to use deferreds. Assuming you're using jQuery:

```
var twoSecondWait = $.Deferred();
$('#loading-image').show();
// ajax calls in jQuery return promises
var ajaxLoadImage = $.ajax(/* options */{});
setTimeout(function() {
  twoSecondWait.resolve();
}, 2000);

$.when(ajaxLoadImage, twoSecondWait, function(loadImageResponse) {
  $('#loading-image').hide();
});
```

This will wait at least 2 seconds, and should the ajax call take longer than two seconds, it will display as soon as the ajax returns successful.

Answer (score 0):

First set the loading image to your page then hide it using jquery at document start and then on ajax call show it.

try this in jquery:

```
$("#loading").hide();                        // hiding loading img at document start  

$(".btnSignin").click(function () {

    $("#loading").show();                    // its jpg or gif loading image
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: mydata
        type: "post",
        success: function (result) {
        $("#loading").hide();            // now the call succeeded so no need to show loading img
        }
    });

});
```